# Raring doesn't give option to run plain text document

Tags: 13.04, executable

I have a line of code saved in a text file on the desktop. In 12.10 there was a popup that asked me what I wanted to do with the file:

Run | Run In Terminal | Edit | Cancel

or something similar to that. The file does have "Run as an Executable" checked. Now it opens by default in the text editor. :[ How can I get the files to run from the desktop in 13.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the desktop Click on `Places`->`Computer`.

In the window which opens up, Press <kbd>F10</kbd> and click on `Preferences`

You will see a window like this. Click on

> Ask each time

And close it. Now Ubuntu should ask you every time, what would you like to do

[image]